# How to measure elapsed time of SQL query in DB2?

Tags: sql, database, db2, elapsedtime

For performance purposes, I'd like to measure the amount of time it took for db2 to execute /process my SQL query. Is there a simple way to achieve this? The IBM documentation is very detailed with no examples.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a timer and evaluate the time from when you called the SQL procedure to the time it took to get the results in your server-side method? While it wont give you exact time you could compare other query methods which will follow same execution cycle. In the rpg program you could store the system date from when you executed query to when it is done and calculate the difference, you need to use the TIME command or the %DATE() function. Then use %DIFF. Or here is a good  start http://www.mcpressonline.com/tips-techniques/rpg/techtip-elapsed-time-function.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tool for measuring performance - including executiontime etc. for a single (or multiple) queries:  `db2batch`
Using `-i complete` will give you granular time information showing prepare time, execution time etc.
Check details in [documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002043.html?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IBM Data Studio](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/data/) to generate query schemas with timings, index usages etc ...